# How to change Carbon's diffForHumans Formatting

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to implement a comment section in my project and want to show how long ago the comment was posted.

So i did:

```
 {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
```

And the output was

```
  3 hours from now
```

But the output that i want is

```
3 hours ago
```

Am i missing something ? I'm doing this in laravel

Comment: Have you tried to do it the other way, `Carbon::now()->diffForHumans($carbon->created_at)`?

Comment: i tried this , I just started learning laravel so i dont really know abt Eloquent, I got error abt needing a carbon class so does that mean i need to create a carbon model

Comment: Definitely, Carbon's namespace is `use Carbon\Carbon;` its not Eloquent. Now I am doubtful if using the way I gave you would give you the expected output. Check: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Comment: thanks for the help anyway i'm just gonna go with what i have right now

Comment: You can attempt the answer I gave.

Comment: "from now" means it's in the future. "ago" means the time is in the past.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use, this `$comment->created_at->diffForHumans(null, true)` to remove the `ago,from now, etc` then you can append the ago by yourself . So you'll end up with:

```
$comment->created_at->diffForHumans(null, true).' ago'
```

> (NB: you may need to check why this does not work by default)
>
> Ref: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Comment: yup i just did that and came here to find your answer Thanks anyway <em> 

          {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans(null,true) }} ago

         </em>

Comment: Glad you got it.

Comment: @robspin I am not sure I have answer to the question... but I think it should be possible...

Comment: More precise it is `$date->diffForHumans($otherDate, \Carbon\CarbonInterface::DIFF_ABSOLUTE)`. A boolean value works, but it's not typed as intended.

Answer (score 0):

diffForHumans("null",true, true);
You need to pass like this so you will end up with

1 hour ago = 1h
25 minutes ago = 25 m